# Python returns generator object without yield

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, return, generator

I am trying to generate a function which tells me if a word is an isogram (contains duplicate values). However, this code always returns a generator object.

```
def is_isogram(string):
    return (True if (string.lower().count(letter) == 1) else False for letter in string.lower())
```

I know how to solve the problem, I was just wondering what is wrong with my code.

Comment: why do you have round brackets around the retrun? can you specify wht are you trying to return? List of True False for each word? if that is true you need to do `return [True if (string.lower().count(letter) == 1) else False for letter in string.lower()]`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it. It returns a generator, which is fine (unless that's not what you want, but you say you know how to solve that). The only problem is that `True if cond else False` when `cond` is already `bool`, just use `cond`.

Comment: Side note: Weird that you say `True` when a letter occurs once, when your description says you want the function to tell whether the word has duplicate letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your function is intended to return a boolean, but the `return` statement has an iteration happening, where each value is mapped to a boolean. The parentheses give you an iterator over those booleans. The function's description suggests that the function should return `True` when the input has duplicate letters, but the mapping gives `True` when a letter is *not* duplicate. So you have three problems:

- The iterator
- The multiple booleans, when you want *one* boolean
- The booleans indicate the inverse of what you want to return

So your idea for an algorithm should be changed to this:

```
def is_isogram(string):
    return any(letter for letter in string.lower() if string.lower().count(letter) > 1)
```

Side note: this algorithm is not efficient. More efficient is to create a set:

```
def is_isogram(string):
    return len(set(string.lower())) < len(string)
```

Answer (score 2):

By wrapping your returned value into parenthesis you've created a generator expression, check https://peps.python.org/pep-0289/ for details.